# Intellisense is not suggesting MonoBehaviour methods or recognizing them

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, intellisense

i am new to working with unity and its intellisense, its been working fine until i tried adding new methods like **FixedUpdate** method and things like that but the intellisense is not showing me any suggestions after typing void I tried doing every thing other people said but to no avail.

i am using visual studio code

Comment: I suggest you to use visual studio and not vscode

Comment: @CristianoSchiaffella, is there any solid reason why you don't suggest vscode? vscode is light and easy to use with multiple extensions available. It makes life easier compared to visual studio. In visual studio, you even have to install an extension that lets you format on save

Comment: I didn't say I dont suggest vscode, but there is a reason if unity is shipped with Visual Studio as default, as it is more powerful (instellisense for code completion, dependency management, refactoring and tips, unit testing support and more and more) and specifically designed to work in c#.
I love vscode but when it comes to working in C # there is no comparison with visual studio.

Comment: Unity said they are dropping support for Vscode that’s a good reason

Comment: yeah thank you all i switched to visual studio and its all good now